# Regex for searching method bodies in source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I need to find method bodies in iOS source code. I've started from writing simple regex: `\{.*\}` but things goes complex when I need to handle nested parentheses.

So I started to think from another direction. I tried to detect method declaration with something like this: `[+-].+ \{`, so I can find end of method with next pattern: `\}\s+[+-]`, but here's bad case for it:

```
- (void)method:(id)arg0 :(id)arg1 third:(id)arg3 {
...
}

#pragma mark - Bla-bla

- method2:(id)arg0 {
   code(
   {
   });
   if (1) {
   }
   -1;
}
```

Can you have any ideas or algorithms or regex to detect method bodies correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis)

Comment: @HamZa So how can I implement balanced group on obj-c?

Comment: I'm now hesitating. I read it as C#. So I'm not sure if it's possible in objective-c. I will remove my closevote...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741279/how-do-you-remove-parentheses-words-within-a-string-using-nsregularexpression It was said there, that there is no matching nested parenthesis in obj-c regex

Comment: It seems to me that you need a parser - that seems to be the only sure way to deal with this. The moment you have a string constant with a `}` or such in it, code that relies on just regular expressions is likely to break down - unless you make it "clever enough" to understand the entire context. At which point you have a parser...

Comment: @Floris I think I have to learn how to use clang tools. From what I know about it, it should resolve my problem