# How to remove text within parentheses using NSRegularExpression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I try to remove part of the string which is inside parentheses.

As an example, for the string `"(This should be removed) and only this part should remain"`, after using NSRegularExpression it should become `"and only this part should remain"`.

I have this code, but nothing happens. I have tested my regex code with RegExr.com and it works correctly. I would appreciate any help.

```
NSString *phraseLabelWithBrackets = @"(test text) 1 2 3 text test";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/\\(([^\\)]+)\\)/g" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *phraseLabelWithoutBrackets = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:phraseLabelWithBrackets options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phraseLabelWithBrackets length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(phraseLabelWithoutBrackets);
```

Comment: Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741279/how-do-you-remove-parentheses-words-within-a-string-using-nsregularexpression?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the regex delimiters and make sure you also exclude `(` in the character class:

```
NSString *phraseLabelWithBrackets = @"(test text) 1 2 3 text test";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\([^()]+\\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *phraseLabelWithoutBrackets = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:phraseLabelWithBrackets options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phraseLabelWithBrackets length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(phraseLabelWithoutBrackets);
```

See this [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/DCvmPd) and [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD9pG3/1).

The `\([^()]+\)` pattern will match

- `\(` - an open parenthesis
- `[^()]+` - 1 or more characters other than `(` and `)`  (change `+` to `*` to also match and remove empty parentheses `()`)
- `\)` - a closing parenthesis